# Samsung SyncMaster 3 cannot show resolutions up from 800x600 despite manual saying otherwise

Tags: crt-monitor

I am in the proud possession of a Samsung SyncMaster 3 monitor. In the reports and in the manual it says it can run 1024x768, but I cannot for the life of me make the resolution higher than 800x600.
Please help me. Here are the manuals and reports in question :
https://www.atarimagazines.com/compute/issue148/138_Samsung_SyncMaster_3.php
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/145641/Samsung-Syncmaster-3.html
[image: What my monitor looks like when I try to up the scale.]
If it helps, I am trying to make it work with a modern laptop via a hdmi to vga converter.

Comment: Higher refresh rates can limit the maximum resolution. Back-of-the-envelope calculation says 1024 x 768 at 75Hz is about 60 megapixels/sec, which I suppose requires a ~60 MHz bandwidth, and the manual says it'll do up to 45 MHz.  What refresh rate are you using?  (Similar considerations apply to the adapter).

Comment: Pfft. My 2048×1536 [Vision Master Pro](https://aperturegrille.fandom.com/wiki/IIYAMA_Vision_Master_Pro_514) laughs at your puny resolution.

Comment: isn't it interesting how the monitor was marketed with the name SyncMaster? Nowadays there is zero chance that a user buying a monitor would care about anything like "sync" but clearly this was a thing when this monitor was made.

Comment: @user253751 It's puzzling how you can even claim that. A _very_ quick glance on every website selling monitors will show that they brag about support for either AMD FreeSync, NVIDIA G-Sync etc.

Answer (score 26):

According to your [manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/145641/Samsung-Syncmaster-3.html?page=15#manual), the monitor can only do 1024x768 *interlaced*; I strongly suspect you're sending 1024x768 progressive (i.e. non-interlaced).

Comment: Sounds good. We used to have a Syncmaster (not sure which model exactly) and I had to use 1024x768 interlaced although the video card could do the resolution non-interlaced.

Comment: How would I be able to send interlaced?

Comment: @FrankenPC That's likely hard-wired into your HDMI/VGA converter and not something you can control.

Comment: @bta Partially true. Both the PC (as a whole, OS, video drivers) needs to support sending it, and the converter needs to support receiving it from HDMI and outputing it on VGA. The problem is, the converter hardware might support it, but it may not advertize it in the list of supported formats, or firmware might not support that format. The PC might not support selecting that format as output, even if the converter would support it. But anyway, if the PC does not have that format in the list of selectable output formats for that converter, there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Honestly, you would probably be unhappy with the eyestrain from interlacing. Supporting it is more a marketing gimmick than how the monitor's really meant to be used.

Comment: @Sneftel: That depends upon the tasks to be performed and the ambient level of illumination.  A typical 1024x768 interlaced mode will show 86 fields/second (43 frames/second).  If one is showing content without excessive contrast between consecutive scan lines, and the room brightness is low enough that one can use the display at a reasonably dim setting, flicker will be far less objectionable than if one is e.g. showing a pattern with lots of alternating black and white horizontal lines.

Answer (score 10):

The monitor is likely not the problem.

Your modern HDMI to VGA converter or your modern computer (includes OS, video card, and video card drivers) just may not support or don't allow selecting send 1024x768 in interlaced mode, or if they do, you did not select an interlaced video mode.

The adapter also may not advertize support of the 1024x768i format so then it will not be in list of supported formats.

If your PC supports forcibly setting the format to 1024x768i, then the adapter may or may not support converting it to analog output.

Comment: Forcibly setting the format may or may not work depending on your OS version.  I had trouble moving from Windows XP to Windows 7 on one PC for this very reason.